# systemd automount unit: run only when server is reachable

Tags: systemd, automounting

I am using systemd automount units (see below) to mount network shares on my laptop
(debian bullseye). This works fine in principle but I have one big issue:

At home it is enough to set TimeoutSec to 2 s in the mount unit. Normally the server is
available and the share is mounted. If the server is down I need to wait for just 2 s
until I see it is not there. Thats ok.

But when not at home and using a vpn, the mount unit will not mount with TimeoutSec set to 2 s.
I need to set it to at least 10 s. Then the mount works. But using 10 s means I always have
to wait 10 s for each share the system tries to reach and is not available. This is really
annoying when starting libreoffice for example (which seems to check for the last used
documents on startup).

What I would like to do is to put a test for server availabilty (e.g. ping -c 1 $SERVER)
into the automount file. When the server is not available, automount is not run.
Is this possible? Or do I need to create a spcial unit and put something like

```
Requires=nfs-server-online.target
```

in my automount unit? And how would the nfs-server-online unit look like?

Regards,

Jürgen

/etc/systemd/system/mnt-share.automount:

```
[Unit]
Description=autoount share

[Automount]
Where=/mnt/share
TimeoutIdleSec=1min

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/systemd/system/mnt-share.mount:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount share

[Mount]
Where=/mnt/share
What=lana:/share
Type=nfs
Options=soft,async
TimeoutSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```